# "Module... should not reference module" error for any C++ project from template

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

I tried to create an empty project with enabled C++, and got that error message almost immediately when the editor is not open. Any ideas what’s wrong?

UE 5.1.1, installed by Epic installer, all VS components are selected as in doc (I double checked). I guess that something's wrong with my Visual Studio installation. That's new setup, it never worked, so no history of that issue. Blueprint only projects could be opened well at the same time.

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat Development Win64 -Project="C:/Users/foobar/Unreal/TestProject/TestProject.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" Development Win64 -Project="C:/Users/foobar/Unreal/TestProject/TestProject.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Log file: C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
Creating makefile for TestProjectEditor (no existing makefile)
Module 'WebMMoviePlayer' (Engine Plugins) should not reference module 'WebMMedia' (Marketplace). Hierarchy is Marketplace -> Engine Programs -> Engine Plugins -> Engine.
```

Answer (score 0):

don't name your project with the engine "keywords" : project, editor, plugin, umg etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's good advice, but unfortunately is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

First, I found out that there are lots of packages in the "Marketplace" folder. I didn't install it myself, but I experimented with some other packages, so seems like it was installed automatically or by a script, and I missed and didn't recognize that moment. These "WebMMoviePlayer" was there.

I tried to remove all content from the "Marketplace" because I didn't need them at all. It didn't solve the problem completely because it broke some other dependency.

When became sure that the problem was in extra plugins, I deleted the UE folder completely and installed it again. Definitely it wasn't the best way, but it worked.